# Trying to get data from an API using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using `fetch()` and the Ticketmaster API I'm trying to access `[[PromiseValue]]` in the log, but keep getting undefined.

```
const API_key = '1234'

fetch(`https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=1&apikey=${API_key}`)
      .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
      .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Is this code failing in some way?  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I had to rephrase the question because I was not even at that step yet. What I'm trying to do currently with this API is access [[PromiseValue]] in the log, but I'm getting undefined.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're describing.  What is "[[PromiseValue]]"?  What is being returned by the server in this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then(response => console.log(response.json()))` is returning `undefined` as the `console.log` method doesn't return any value;

Update your code to use the actual value:

**Option 1:**

```
fetch(https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=1&apikey=${API_key})
  .then(response => {
      var response = response.json();
      console.log(response);
      return response;
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

**Option 2:**

```
fetch(https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=1&apikey=${API_key})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

If you further wanted to utilize the data returned from the API, you have to understand what the shape of the data is and define what you want to do with it. Looking at their docs quickly, if you want to get the name of the first event returned in your query, you could replace `.then(data => console.log(data))` with

```
.then(data => console.log(data._embedded.events[0].name)) // logs it to the console
```

**OR**

```
.then(data => alert(data._embedded.events[0].name)) // creates an alert with the name in it
```

**OR**

```
.then(data => {
  var ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.innerHTML = data._embedded.events[0].name;
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(ele);
}); // creates a div with the name in it and appends it to your page
```

Comment: thanks, now from this how would I go about accessing data from the log? sorry I'm a new programmer and using API's are very new challenging for me.

Comment: Happy to help, but it is very unclear to me what you are trying to do. You wouldn't access data from the log. Logging is one useful tool that can help figure out what is happening if you are having problems. In the line `data => console.log(data)`, data is your data, so you would do whatever you want with it there. You can log it to the console(as is being done above) or something else, but you will need to provide more details in order to get more help.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to access data in the Ticketmaster API and I'm not sure what the next steps would be. I know this is a pretty general question, but more specifically I'm trying enable a search for events in the Ticketmaster API.

Comment: Updated my answer with some options, but you still aren't being that specific. Hope it helps.